# Changing currency symbol in SQL Reporting 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, formatting, globalization

I'm using SQL Reporting 2005. I'm formatting a currency in a cell using

```
Format(Fields!NetPrice.Value, "C")
```

but the format is coming out

```
$10.00
```

I want pounds so

```
£10.00
```

Can someone tell me where is the setting to do this. I've looked and google and can't find it. Is it obvious? I want to set it on the report level if possible and not alter SQL Server settings due to minimise impact elsewhere.

I could cast the currency to a string and add `"£"` I guess but I want to do it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to manually edit the RDL file. I guess you couldn't see the language section as you didn't have the report selected.

To see the report properties click on the background behind the outline of the report (the yellow section) and check the properties window or select 'Report' from the drop down when viewing the properties window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, formats for date, currency, and numbers are determined by the report server language at run time.

To override the formatting provided through the report server language, you can set the Language property within the report when you design it. This can be set at the report level or the TextRun level. If you want to vary the formatting based on the language or local settings of the browser or client application, you can set the Language property to an expression that includes the User!Language variable.

This info was provided [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

---

On the Report you can set the Language Property which is in the Localization section. You will place the language code like en-GB in this property. You can also do this at the field level too if you want. This should pick-up on your Regional and Language settings on your PC. If you want to override this or control this then you can simply set the report property accordingly.

If you set this property and then view the code of the report (RDL) you will see this towards the very bottom:

```
 <Language>en-GB</Language>
```

This information will be used for currency, date, and numeric conversions.

Comment: Sorry confused. I'm looking at report properties and not seeing language at all. Is it not on 2005 perhaps. I've got User!Language but how would I use this? Is there and override to Format maybe or can I force it elsewhere on the report. Bit of a noob in this area I'm afraid

Comment: brilliant. <Language>en-GB</Language> works. I had to manual amend the rdl in notpad to change though. Sure I've just missed the UI bit to change it but great - job done. Thank you